# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using XML design vs text tab in Android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

It should be easier to use the design tab when designing an app, as you can drag and drop and it is more intuitive, but it seems many developers rather prefer to use the text tab (write the design in code).
Furthermore, in the Udacity course videos I'm currently watching they teach you to design the app using code.

Any special reasons why one is preferable to the other?

Comment: In my experience, the drag-and-drop often doesn't drop things where you want them to--it can be hell to position it just right, especially if you're working with complex layouts. Also, it autonames ids for you, which can be a pain to go back and fix later. With code it's easier to customize what you want and where you want it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion you should omit using designing your layouts with the visual editor as much as you can. You might be tempted to use it at the beginning of your "android journey", but it won't do you any good in a long term.

Using text editor will basically make you understand layouts. How they work, how `Views` influence each other. If you learn that, I assure you, making a layout with the text editor will be much, much faster than using the visual designing tool.

I personally never use this tool (the visual one) for creating a layout. Sometimes I'm just peeking at the `Preview` window (while writing in a text editor) to see if everything goes as planned.